# Handling push notifications received while app in background

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo

Im trying to set the badge number correctly for received notifications. The only way to deal with notifications received while the app was in background is using Taskmanager as I understand. I did everything as seen but its just not working /incoming notifications are not logged etc when in background.

```
const BACKGROUND_NOTIFICATION_TASK = 'BACKGROUND-NOTIFICATION-TASK'; 

TaskManager.defineTask(BACKGROUND_NOTIFICATION_TASK, ({ data, error, executionInfo }) => {     
console.log('Received a notification in the background!'); //this never logs }); 
Notifications.registerTaskAsync(BACKGROUND_NOTIFICATION_TASK); 

const App = () => {...}
```

app.json:

```
"infoPlist": { 
"UIBackgroundModes": ["remote-notification"] }
```

when sending notification i add:   "content-available": 1, and also tried: "_contentAvailable": true  What am I doing wrong?